# How to compare decimal numbers in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, bc

```
#!/bin/bash
for input in $(cat status_cpu.txt)
do
      cpu=`ssh -i  root@$input 'top -b -n1' | grep "load" | awk '{print $12}'`

      max=2.02

if [ $(echo "$cpu < $max" | bc -l ) ]; then
    echo "yes"
else
    echo "no" 
fi
done
```

cat status_cpu.txt
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2

I want to compare decimal points in shell script.

Comment: FWIW, it's easier to use `uptime` than `top` to get the system load...

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use `awk` and `grep` in same line, `awk` does it all.
Do not use old and outdated back-tics, use parentheses.

So this would change from:

```
cpu=`ssh -i  root@$input 'top -b -n1' | grep "load" | awk '{print $12}'`
```

To:

```
cpu=$(ssh -i  root@$input 'top -b -n1' | awk '/load/ {print $12}')
```

---

And this:

```
if [ $(echo "$cpu < $max" | bc -l ) -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "yes"
else
    echo "no" 
fi
```

Could be written

```
[ $(echo "$cpu < $max" | bc -l ) -eq 1 ] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

or

```
[[ $(echo "$cpu < $max" | bc -l ) -eq 1 ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

Comment: Most helpful answer for me although I had to add a `-eq 1` in the [] if statements; otherwise it was entering the if even with an exit code of 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use comparison using `bc -l` like this:

```
max='2.02'
s='2.01'

bc -l <<< "$max > $s"
1

s='2.05'
bc -l <<< "$max > $s"
0
```

So `bc -l` expression will print 1 for success and 0 for failure.

Comment: This is tested in `bash`, Make sure you are using `bash` shell. Otherwise use pipes: `echo "$max > $s" | bc -l`

Comment: If you want help spend some time in typing and provide all the information about your env first. What shell are you using? What is your `bc` version? What command did you try and what error you got?

Comment: if [ $(echo "$cpu < $max" | bc -l ) ]; then
    echo "yes"
else
    echo "no" 
fi                            bc 1.06.95   GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)     | (standard_in) 1: syntax error

Comment: It should be: `if [ $(echo "$cpu < $max" | bc -l ) = 1 ]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi` and you must use `echo "[$cpu]"` to check value of `$cpu` before `bc` command.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to put this into a Posix shell function which can thereafter be easily used in shell tests (presumably bc reserves return codes for error codes):

```
ifbc () { test $(echo "$@" | bc -l ) -ne 0; }
```

And an example usage of this function:

```
ifbc "$max > $s" && echo "true, it's greater" || echo "no, it's less or ="
```